# Trying to Line Up Divs

Tags: css, layout, css-float

It might be that time in the evening, but I can't work out how to line up these `article` elements. When one of my articles has more text, it stops the rest of the articles from floating left properly.

I've set up a demo here: http://codepen.io/realph/pen/eumyj

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest approach (though it has limited support), would be to use CSS3 `columns`:

[**UPDATED EXAMPLE HERE**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HlzFJ)

```
.container {
    background: brown;
    width: 940px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    columns: 4;
    -webkit-columns: 4;
    -moz-columns: 4;
}
```

Alternatively, just make the elements `inline-block` as opposed to floating elements, and then use `vertical-align:top` for alignment.

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zmBGf)

```
article {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    background: yellow;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Another approach would be to use `nth-child` to clear the fourth elements:

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AgBtG)

```
article:nth-child(4n+1) {
   clear: both;
}
```

Comment: That's fantastic, but I don't think I can use CSS3 columns on this project. Also, I need all rows to be in line with one another.

Comment: @realph Alright, I added two alternatives, however, as you point out, they aren't exactly inline. I'm afraid the only alternative would be to use JS if you can't use columns.

Comment: If you want them all to be the same height, you can set the container to `display: table` and the articles to `display: table-cell`, although you'll then have to organize them into rows (wrapping divs around each row group).

Comment: Thank you for three brilliant answers!